# Terraform cant create VM in openstack provider (No suitable endpoint could be found in the service catalog)

Tags: terraform, openstack

I have project in terraform - provider "openstack" v1.16:

```
  provider "openstack" {
  auth_url = "${var.auth_url}"
  user_name = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  project_domain_id = "${var.project_id}"
  project_domain_name = "${var.project_domain_name}"
  endpoint_type = "public"
}
```

And try to create compute node:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "terraform_test" {
  name = "test"
  region = "${var.region}"
  availability_zone = "nova"
  image_id = "${var.image}"
  flavor_name = "m1.medium"
  key_pair = "${var.ssh_key}"
  security_groups = ["default"]

  network {
    uuid = "${var.network}"
  }
}
```

"terraform plan" without any errors.

When a try to apply plan, i take this error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform_test: 1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform_test: Error creating OpenStack compute client: No suitable endpoint could be found in the service catalog.
```

When i do

```
openstack catalog list
```

I take

```
 nova        compute   regionName
                         public: https://compute.$url:8774/v2.1
                       regionName   
                         admin: $url
                       regionName
                         internal: $url

 keystone    identity  regionName
                         internal: $url
                       regionName
                         admin: $url
                       regionName
                         public: https://auth.$url:5000/v2.0
```

So i have endpoint for computing (create vm's). What is the problem?

Comment: Not used OpenStack in a long, long time (and only barely at that) but the [provider docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/index.html#overriding-service-api-endpoints) have an option for overriding the endpoints that might be useful here. It does come with a big warning that most people don't need that but I don't know if your setup is one of those that would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
openstack provide *-openrc.sh script with all environment variables for connection:

```
# With the addition of Keystone we have standardized on the term **tenant**
# as the entity that owns the resources.
export OS_TENANT_ID=$ID
export OS_TENANT_NAME="$NAME"

# unsetting v3 items in case set
unset OS_PROJECT_ID
unset OS_PROJECT_NAME
unset OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME
```

I found out that I used variables for API v3, but post them to API v2. So I changed variables names with the same values:

```
project_domain_id > tenant_id
project_domain_name > tenant_name
```

Provider now looks like:

```
provider "openstack" {
  auth_url = "${var.auth_url}"
  user_name = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  tenant_name = "${var.tenant_name}"
  tenant_id = "${var.tenant_id}"
}
```

Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for quite a while with this error:

> "*Error creating OpenStack compute client: No suitable endpoint could be found in the service catalog*"

I got this message when trying to do anything with the Terraform OpenStack provider. What puzzled me was that I was able to create infrastructures without any problems using the command-line client.

Here are the measures I took that ultimately led to a solution of the problem. I'm not sure which one of them was the decisive one but perhaps a combination of them might help.

#### 1. enable debugging in Terraform

by setting `export TF_LOG=DEBUG` This might help identify the source of the issue

#### 2. reset Terraform

- `rm terraform.tfstate`
- `rm -rf .terraform`

Not sure about this but if you haven't managed to set up any infrastructure you might want to do such a reset.

#### 3.unset all `OS_` variables

`unset $(set | grep -o "^OS_[A-Za-z0-9_]*")`

(note: this will spare the variable `OSTYPE` on a Mac)

I had already noticed when using the `openstack` command-line client that these `OS_*` variables were causing troubles, especially when switching back and forth from authentication with RC file to authentication with application credentials file. This is the command I always have in my scripts before sourcing an RC or app-cred file:

```
unset OS_USERNAME OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME OS_PROJECT_ID OS_PROJECT_NAME OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID
```

But this time I unset `OS_AUTH_TYPE` noticing that it was set to `v3applicationcredential`.

Other `OS_` variables to unset:

```
unset OS_AUTH_TYPE OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION OS_REGION_NAME
```

Or just unset all `OS_` variables with the command mentioned above.

---

Some suggest to look at the OpenStack endpoints with `openstack endpoint list` but to run this command one needs to have administrator rights on OpenStack, which I don't have. In the end, I managed to fix the issue without having to contact the OpenStack admins.

Answer (score 0):

Also faced this problem. The solution for me was to delete the terraform state and than just run a `terraform init` and `terraform apply`.

After having a deeper look the problem was that in the background the OpenStack Volume API changed from v2 to v3.
So the terraform state had some orphans that were linked to resources of API v2, which caused the error message:

> Error creating OpenStack block storage client: No suitable endpoint could be found in the service catalog

You can check this by running `terraform state list`